# Send push to multiple devices FCM (Web) unable to generate notification key

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I am trying to figure how to group multiple tokens ids and do a "Group messaging" not through topic group. The document says the response will send a unique notification key:

1. Using FCM
2. Group multiple devices
3. Web push through JavaScript

Here is the Postman request I am sending:

[image]

See the response:

[image]

But I am not getting the unique notification KEY as per the document from google FCM .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the ***endpoint*** for sending a message:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

Resulting for it to return a response as if you sent a message. It ignores the other parameters (`operation`, `notification_key_name`) and uses only `registration_ids`.

As seen in the sample POST request in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#managing-device-groups-on-the-app-server) (the docs is under Android, **but** the sample is a POST request so it shouldn't matter), you should use:

```
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification
```

Comment: Thanks , i tired earlier with the same URL but it didn't work .The mistake was i used project id as project id but project id should be sender_id which i replaced and it worked finally   Thanks for the help